# Segmented speech data, save it as a .wav file and play it in Matlab

Tags: matlab, speech

I have speech data, which I segment into some parts. I am trying to create a `.wav` file for each segmented data and play this `.wav` file.

For example, suppose the speech data is an `1x1000` array called `data`. I segment this data into 4 parts using the indices of `seg_data`.

```
seg_data
    1     250
    251   500
    501   750
    751   1000
```

Code:

```
for i=1:size(seg_data(:,1))
    w(i)=data(seg_data(i,1): seg_data(i,2));
    wavwrite(w(i),'file_%d \n ',i);
end
```

First thing I need to create one folder in which the `.wav` file that is created in every iteration is stored. Then, I can read the stored file one by one and can play it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the sampling frequency *Fs*, you have to use the signature `wavwrite(y,filename)` as presented in the [reference](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html) site.

```
for i=1:size(seg_data(:,1))
    w(i,:)=data(seg_data(i,1): seg_data(i,2));
    wavwrite(w(i,:),['file_',num2str(i)]);
end
```

BTW, the documentation suggests to use `audiowrite` instead.

Comment: how to store all created .wav file in each iterations in one folder.

Comment: In order to have a clear order in SO. First, if the proposed answer solved your problem, please marked it as the 'accepted answer'. Second, start a new Question with any additional problem. Thank you.